# Does parent see pipe eof on child exit?

Tags: c, pipe, eof, file-pointer

Suppose you create a `pipe` and then `fork`. In the parent, you `close` the writing end and `fdopen` the reading end to get a `FILE*`. In the child, you `close` `stdout`, `dup2` the write end of the pipe to `stdout`, `close` both ends of the pipe, and `exec`. Under what conditions, e.g what the `exec`d child does or other calls made in the parent, will the parent see `eof` on the `FILE*` when the child exits after consuming `stdout` or will calls like `getline` hang?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, and I saw getline hang after reading all the output of the child. So I suppose the real question is under what conditions will the parent see feof. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Admittedly without testing, I'd assume the reading process would have to see some notification, else the `grep` process in an `ls | grep somefilename` pipeline would never exit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I would think so too, but maybe there are other calls involved besides just the ones I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard I/O library uses `read(2)` and `write(2)` under the hood; the behavior of `read(2)` is to return 0 to indicate EOF when there is no more data available in the pipe and no active writers (the standard I/O library then converts this to the negative EOF constant that we all know).

So, if you set things up properly, `getline()` will not hang and it will return -1.

If you see `getline()` hanging even when the child has terminated and closed the pipe, you probably left the pipe write channel opened somewhere else. Double check to make sure that the parent has closed the write channel before calling `getline()`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you've set up the pipe correctly (and it sounds like you have), the parent should indeed see EOF.  The related issue is that the parent also has to take care to `wait` for the child, otherwise the child is left as a zombie.

Answer (score 0):

When a process terminates for any reason the operating system closes all remaining open file descriptors.

For pipes, files and sockets pending data is first written/sent by the OS. The other peer receives the pending data followed by `EOF`, no "proper set up" is necessary.